# Install mySQL on Redhat specifying a different location

Tags: mysql

I need to put the datafiles for mySQL 5.5 community server on a different location than the default (it would be helpful if the log could go there too). Is this something I can do at the command line or after install.

This is on Redhat

Comment: different location on the same server?

Comment: @BookOfZeus yes a different location on the same server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the only way to do this is by building from source and specifying the home during Make. I would put down instructions but I am having a devil of a time getting it to build.